# WPF. DataGrid. Как удалить элемент из таблицы и БД

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть таблица:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,449,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер ПК" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Прізвище" Binding="{Binding Path=First_name}"/>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="видалити" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="відкрити пк"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Как в коде получить значение колонки (`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер ПК" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>`), чтоб потом по ИД удалить запись? Помогите плиз!

Comment: с-шарпик........

Comment: да все равно, главное - не сильно запудрено...

Comment: Ваш вопрос решен?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, решил проблему говнокодом, удручает...

Comment: Написал ответ...по поводу БД не могу ничего сказать, т.к. по ней вы не дали никакой информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таким случаях можно использовать команды (как уже отмечали в комментариях):

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Button Content="видалити" 
                   Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
           <Button Content="відкрити пк" />
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

В вашей ViewModel определяете соответствующую команду `RemoveCommand`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Info> Data { get; set; }

public void Remove(object param)
{
    Info select = param as Info;
    Data.Remove(select);
}

public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
  RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand(Remove);
  Data = new ObservableCollection<Info>(GetData());
}
```

Вместо `Info`, естественно, должен быть ваш класс.